# Where does socket.io store its data in redis?

Tags: javascript, redis, socket.io

I am using redis store as my client socket store as I run my app using elastic beanstalk on multiple servers. 
This is how i do it

```
var socket_io_store;
socket_io_store = new socket_io_redis({
    redisPub: redis.createClient(6379, utils.database),
    redisSub: redis.createClient(6379, utils.database),
    redisClient: redis.createClient(6379, utils.database)
});
```

But I cannot see the socket related data stored anywhere in redis. Where can I find the socket client data in redis? I can see my express related session data in redis but not socket related data.